# How can you split a csv file into multiple files based on the value of a column java?

Tags: java, csv

I need to find a way to split a csv file into multiple csv files based on the value of a particular column of my input csv file. I need the name of the newly generated csv files to be the value of that column as well.

```
For example:

input CSV file = 

Col1,Col2,Col3
1,2,Cat
1,3,Cat
2,4,Dog
2,5,Dog

I want to split by Col3 so I get the following table and file name:

---------------- File name = Cat.csv
Col1,Col2,Col3
1,2,Cat
1,3,Cat



---------------- File name = Dog.csv
Col1,Col2,Col3
2,4,Dog
2,5,Dog
```

Any way to do this?

Thanks for any help.

So, far i can only do only reading file and saving in a object.

```
    package com.jcg;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class CsvFileReader {

    private static final String COMMA_DELIMITER = ",";

    private static final int ORDER_ID_IDX = 0;
    private static final int ORDER_DATE_IDX = 1;
    private static final int ORDER_COUNTRY_IDX = 2;
    private static final int ORDER_VALUE = 3;

    public static void readCsvFile(String fileName) {

        BufferedReader fileReader = null;

        try {

            List<Order> orders = new ArrayList<Order>();

            String line = "";

            fileReader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(fileName));

            fileReader.readLine();

            while ((line = fileReader.readLine()) != null) {
                String[] tokens = line.split(COMMA_DELIMITER);
                if (tokens.length > 0) {
                    Order order = new Order(Long.parseLong(tokens[ORDER_ID_IDX]), tokens[ORDER_DATE_IDX],
                            tokens[ORDER_COUNTRY_IDX], tokens[ORDER_VALUE]);
                    orders.add(order);
                }
            }

            for (Order order : orders) {
                System.out.println(order.toString());

            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("Error in CsvFileReader !!!");
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            try {
                fileReader.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                System.out.println("Error while closing fileReader !!!");
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

    }

}
```

**Order.java**

```
    package com.jcg;

public class Order {

    private long id;
    private String dates;
    private String country;
    private String values;

    public Order(long id, String dates, String country, String values) {
        super();
        this.id = id;
        this.dates = dates;
        this.country = country;
        this.values = values;
    }

    public long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getDates() {
        return dates;
    }

    public void setDates(String dates) {
        this.dates = dates;
    }

    public String getCountry() {
        return country;
    }

    public void setCountry(String country) {
        this.country = country;
    }

    public String getValues() {
        return values;
    }

    public void setValues(String values) {
        this.values = values;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Order [id=" + id + ", dates=" + dates + ", country=" + country + ", values=" + values + "]";
    }
}
```

Comment: well there is an `if` and a `String::equals` - what have you tried?

Comment: updated the post.

Comment: You do not need to save it as an Object first.  `if (token[2].equals ("Cat")) {//writeCat} else {// writeDog}`

Comment: @Scary Wombat I'll be having different values in col3. So, how to modify accordingly to that. It would be great if you guide me with this.

Comment: col3 is `private String values;` in model? @Anjanaa

Comment: yes. Its private String values;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you have list of `Order`

```
List<Order> orders = new ArrayList<Order>();
```

Do group by on list `List<Order> orders` with key as `Col3` (which is `private String values`)  and values as `List<Order>`

```
Map<String,List<Order>> result = orders.stream()
                           .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Order::getValues));
```

Now for each entry in `Map` create `.csv` file with key and write write corresponding values to that file

```
result.forEach((key,value)->{
File newFile = new File(key+".csv");
BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(newFile));
 values.forEach(order->{
         StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
         builder.append(order.getId()+",");
         builder.append(order.getDates()+",");
         builder.append(order.getCountry()+",");
         builder.append(order.getValues()+",");
         writer.write(builder.toString());
         writer.newLine();
        };
         writer.flush();
         writer.close();
   });
```

Comment: printing order is giving me a lot of files.Please help

Comment: what can you explain the problem or show the code @Anjanaa

Comment: `Map<String,List<Order>> result = orders.stream()
                    .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Order::getCountry));
   
   result.forEach((key,value)->{
    File newFile = new File("/Users/ankr/Desktop/files/"+key+".csv");
     try {
      BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(newFile));
//      writer.write(value.toString());
      writer.write(result.get(key).toString());
     } catch (IOException e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
     }
     //now write each 'Order' in value to file
     
   });`

Comment: Not sure how those values will written as a new file.

Comment: i just showed example in the post, check the updated code and you need to take care of handling of exception @Anjanaa

Comment: Awesome. Thanks for help